# Easy question: How to concatenate two React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React here, I have

```
const a = <li> first item </li>
```

and

```
const b = <li> second item </li>
```

I would like to achieve

```
c = <li> first item </li><li> second item </li>
```

But when I use `c=a+b` it just give me [object][object] as output. How to concatenate React components? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in a fragment before returning them?

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

 const b = <li> second item </li>
 const a = <li> first item </li>

 return (
   <>
     {a}
     {b}
   </>
 )
}
```

OR maybe:

```
const c = <>{a}{b}</>
```

You can even return an array of components from render:

```
const SomeComponent = () => [a,b]
```

It really depends on what your goals are.
Show more code and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I don't have more code I was just baby-stepping my way through React. Could you in addition do a for-loop where `a =a+ <li> some item </li>`. thanks again!

Comment: @KY - you can do lots of different stuff, you can even return an array of components from render like [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kyfext)

Answer (score 1):

React Component is using vanilla JS under the hood.

`var header = document.createElement("H1");`

So what you are asking wouldn't make sense. Everything is an object in JS so when you say a+b you are just concatenating two functions. These functions are objects.

What you would want to do instead is map over a list and create the list dynamically. Example

```
return (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item, i) => {
      return <li>item</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
);
```